# 3d flipping div card in css lag

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-transitions

i'm trying to make an effect where the front side of the card rotates on Y axis then the back side of the card shows up, for some reason, when the card rotates it shows the content of the front side for a second before the back side appears, why is this happening?

```css
.movie-card {
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #FFE3D8;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px -15px #fff;  
    transform: scale(1);
    cursor: pointer;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 600ms ;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.frontofcard,
.backofcard {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
}

.frontofcard {
    z-index: 2;
    backface-visibility: hidden;;

}

.backofcard {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    /* transform: rotateY(180deg); */
    background: #343065;
}


.movie-card:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.07);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }

.movie-card:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 0.8;
    transform: scale(0.9);
    
}
```

```html
        <div class="movie-card">
              <div class="frontofcard">
                <div class="image"><img src="https://www.tuppencemagazine.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/The-Joker-DVD-and-Blu-ray-cover-art.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
              </div>
              <div class="backofcard">
                <!-- <div class="title">
                    <div class="tag-box">

                    </div>
                </div> -->
              </div>
          </div>
<!--
```

i hope i made my problem clear, what i'm trying to achieve is to get the back side of the card to the front instantly as the card rotates on hover, so the front side of the card will be on back as long as i hover over the card.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing Opacity of the front-card after hover`.movie-card:hover .frontofcard {opacity: 0;}`. but we don't want it as soon as the hover happens & also not late for that i added transition on both cards `transition: all 300ms;` i choose 300 because your flip animation is 600ms so i think 300ms would be fine.but you can mess around until you find the best timing

```css
.movie-card {
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #FFE3D8;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px -15px #fff;
  transform: scale(1);
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 600ms linear;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.frontofcard,
.backofcard {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 300ms;  /*I Added*/
  
}

.frontofcard {
  z-index: 2;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  
}

.backofcard {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  /* transform: rotateY(180deg); */
  background: #343065;
}

.movie-card:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.07);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.movie-card:hover .frontofcard {   /*I Added*/
  opacity: 0;                      /*I Added*/
}

.movie-card:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="movie-card">
  <div class="frontofcard">
    <div class="image"><img src="https://www.tuppencemagazine.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/The-Joker-DVD-and-Blu-ray-cover-art.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="backofcard">
    <!-- <div class="title">
                    <div class="tag-box">

                    </div>
                </div> -->
  </div>
</div>
<!--
```

Comment: that worked just fine with me, thanks!
though there's still a problem with the card lagging as i hover, do you know what causes that?

Comment: yes because you haven't added the transition type on your main div `movie-card` . i just updated the answer from `transition: all 600ms;`  to `transition: all 600ms linear;`